# Atooma Intent based trigger

Tags: android, android-intent, atooma

I am trying out the Atooma SDK. They provide an abstract class IntentBasedTrigger for creating triggers that fires when the intent fires. The class has an abstract method

```
public String getIntentFilter() throws RemoteException
```

In the docs (http://www.atooma.com/developers#start/trigger) They use this with a standard Android intent. However, I want to use it with a custom Intent, so I made up a string and returned it from getIntentFilter. However, this does not work (I can't be more specific at the moment) which leads me to believe that defining intents is a bit more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

IntentBasedTriggers works with custom Intent as well.

I am part of the Atooma team, unfortunally we don't have a plugin sample with IntentBasedTrigger, but you can see the SnapBack plugin using it

Here is the source code
https://github.com/SnapbackLabs/AtoomaPlugins/blob/master/AtoomaBlowDetectionPlugin/src/com/atooma/plugin/blow/TR_BlowDetectionSensorBased.java#L92

Comment: Hi, I have read the code and couldn't find any clear solutions. I am able to see the plugin in atooma, but when I activate the rule I get an error: The selected atooma cant be enabled. Any guidance on how to debug this?

Comment: Can you send me the APK ot (better) the source code? l.braghetto at atooma.com
The debug with atooma from play store is difficult becouse of proguard